# What could be causing setVolume to work on a Google Pixel but not a Galaxy S9?

Tags: java, android

I am currently trying to output MediaPlayer audio through the left, right, or both channels using the setVolume function. During testing the function works as expected on a Google Pixel 2 XL running 9.0 Pie. When testing on my second device, a Samsung Galaxy S9 running 8.0 Oreo, the audio plays on both channels and seems unaffected by the setVolume calls.

I don't have any errors in the console so I am not quite sure where to start trouble shooting. As stated above the application is tested and working on a Pixel 2 XL w/ 9.0 Pie but not working on Galaxy S9 w/ 8.0 Oreo.

```java
private void audioTestFunction() {
        if (audioSwitch.isChecked()) {
            coolChangeEffect("Stop Audio Test", audioSwitch);

            mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.audio_test);

            mp.setLooping(true);
            mp.start();

            switch (channels.getCheckedRadioButtonId()){
                case R.id.left_channel_button:
                    mp.setVolume(1.0f, 0.0f);
                    break;
                case R.id.both_channels_button:
                    mp.setVolume(1.0f, 1.0f);
                    break;
                case R.id.right_channel_button:
                    mp.setVolume(0.0f, 1.0f);
                    break;
                default:
                    mp.setVolume(1.0f, 1.0f);
                    break;
            }

        } else {
            coolChangeEffect("Audio Test", audioSwitch);
            mp.stop();
        }
    }
```

When executed on the Pixel 2 XL the application sets the volume of each channel depending on what radio button is selected. When executed on the Galaxy S9 the application continues to play on both channels with no volume change no matter what radio button has been selected.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible that your MediaPlayer is still in the **Idle** state after you call `mp.start()` for a few milliseconds. In the [Andoid Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html) it says that if `setVolume` is called from within the Idle state, that no errors will be thrown, however no changes will be encountered to the state of the MediaPlayer.

If this is the problem, a potential fix, would be waiting until `mp.isPlaying()` returns true, before entering your switch statement. It is possible, that Samsung's audio driver has a small latency, and thats causing this issue.

Quote of Android Documentation:

> There is a subtle but important difference between a newly constructed MediaPlayer object and the MediaPlayer object after reset() is called. It is a programming error to invoke methods such as setVolume(float, float)... in the Idle state for both cases.
>
> If any of these methods is called right after a MediaPlayer object is constructed, the user supplied callback method OnErrorListener.onError() won't be called by the internal player engine and the object state remains unchanged; but if these methods are called right after reset(), the user supplied callback method OnErrorListener.onError() will be invoked by the internal player engine and the object will be transfered to the Error state.

Comment: how this attempts answering the question ...or even explain the difference?

Comment: @Dylan I have tried implementing a solution that checks for when `mp.isPlaying()` and a solution that utilizes `mp.setOnPreparedListener()` but neither seem to have resolved the issue unfortunately on the Galaxy S9. The Pixel 2 XL continues to operate as expected with both solution attempts.

Comment: Wow. that is really interesting, I'm wondering if this could be a bug on Samsung's side. Have you tried Martin's answer? It doesn't seem related, but maybe.. Also, I would try changing the volume and putting the same value in both params. Martin's answer made me want to try that, but I'm not there with you.

Comment: I attempted to try @MartinZeitler 's suggestion again but It looks like I am only able to test the speakers but not change any settings. To clarify I am not trying to test my phone's speakers, I am trying to output audio to either left, right, or both channels.

Comment: @Dylan I'm gonna try adjusting the volume using the `setVolume` function as you said (so `setVolume(0.5f, 0.5f)`) and see if I get any results.

Comment: @Dylan changing both values to 0.5f had no effect, it seems to just not recognize the calls at all.

Answer (score 0):

Issue Resolved!

**The original code was correct, the Galaxy S9 needed to be updated to Android 9.0 Pie in order for the `setVolume()` functions to work.**

Following @Dylan's tip I believe this is just a bug on Samsung's part reinforced by the fact that a system update was the solution.